# PHP/MySql if-operator within select statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement, select-query

I have database with several tables, all have one column with same name. I want to fetch data from this column that way so when it's fetched from particular table ("countries"), it has string append, otherwise data is simply fetched. 
Here is my method

```
public function getInfo($table, $id) {
    $operate = $this->pdo->prepare("select if({$table}=='countries', 'concat('capital', city)', 'city') city from {$table} where id= {$id}");
        $operate->execute();

        return $operate->fetchObject();
    }
```

I have several methods within a class and everything works fine. This one also works without if-statement, the problem appears to be with this expression: {$table}=='countries'. However, I couldn't find where my mistake is. I'm new to php and would be glad to know what is the problem with this expression and how shall I get around it.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the curly brackets with backticks?

Comment: Unfortunately, they didn't make much difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly the `${}`-way of string-interpolation in PHP only supports one expression like getting a value from an array. It is not possible to use an if-statement or the ternary operator inside this construct.

This would be an option:

```
$column = ($table == 'countries')? "concat('capital',city)":"city";
$operate = this->pdo->prepare("select $column from {$table} where id= {$id}");
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it works at last. Only when using concat it worked with comma instead of plus - concat('capital', city)